# JetBrains IDEs - shortcut to jump out of brackets / jump to the end of an expression

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Consider this code, where `|` is the cursor

```
expect("Som|eString")
```

I'd like to know if there's a keyboard shortcut to jump to here:

```
expect("SomeString")|
```

Preferably with a dot added, like this:

```
expect("SomeString").|
```

In other words, I feel like a shortcut to jump to the end of an experssion/statement to continue typing it (for example after finishing typing one function's arguments in a function chain) would be very useful, and surely there is one, even if I'm having troubles finding it in the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab when typing** enabled in **Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys**, hitting `Tab` within brackets moves the caret outside the closing bracket.

Note that this only works on initial typing: during subsequent editing, pressing `Tab` inside braces will insert the `Tab` character.

Comment: IMPORTANT: only works on initial typing